# No module named 'telegram.ext'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Использую библиотеку python-telegram-bot
Выдает ошибку:

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.ext'
```

Сам код:

```py
import token_for_bot
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
import logging

def start(update, context):
 context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="hello world!")

start_handler =  CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
 level=logging.INFO)

updater = Updater(token= token_for_bot , use_context= True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

updater.start_polling()
```

Библиотеку установил:

```bsh
pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Библиотека устанавливается просто командой `pip install python-telegram-bot`. Проверьте, что у вас активировано нужное виртуальное окружение

Comment: @SimonOsipov я работаю без виртуального окружения

Comment: Это плохая практика, работать без виртуального окружения. Какая у вас система? Какой Python? Какой командой вы запускаете бота?

Comment: @SimonOsipov LinuxArch, python3+ , python main,py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запуск твоей программы происходит путем команды `python main.py`. Если ты запустишь интерпретатор командой `python`, то увидишь, что он запускает python 2.7, а тебе нужно 3+
Для этого воспользуйся командой `python3 main.py`.

Comment: Даже ексли так кастовать, ошибка та же

Comment: всмысле кастовать?

Comment: покажи, что будет, если написать команду `python`
А потом то, что будет если написать `python3`

Comment: `python` 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
NameError: name 'dispatcher' is not defined

`python3` 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
NameError: name 'dispatcher' is not defined

Оно стало показывать другую ошибку, хотя я откатился до исходного

Comment: Не совсем то, что я имел ввиду, но это подтверждает мой ответ. Ты пытался запускать свою программу в Python2, хотя нужно в Python3. Для этого используется другой alias.

Comment: Что касается твоей ошибки текущей - то да, программа не знает, что такое `dispatcher`, посмотри, пожалуйста, внимательно, откуда ты копировал код и убедись, что ты скопировал все строки.